# Why does Fulltext catalog not work in codebehind?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a query written below:

```
use DBName
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].StackOverflow(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Stackoverflow] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ResponseBody] [nvarchar](max) NULL

 CONSTRAINT [PK_ResponseBody] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].StackOverflow ON
INSERT [dbo].StackOverflow ([Id], [Stackoverflow], [ResponseBody]) VALUES (1, '[Stackoverflow]','[ResponseBody]')
INSERT [dbo].StackOverflow ([Id], [Stackoverflow], [ResponseBody]) VALUES (2, '[Stackoverflow]','[ResponseBody]')
INSERT [dbo].StackOverflow ([Id], [Stackoverflow], [ResponseBody]) VALUES (3, '[Stackoverflow]','[ResponseBody]')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].StackOverflow OFF

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG StackOverflowCatalog CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON StackOverflow (ResponseBody)
KEY INDEX PK_ResponseBody
ON StackOverflowCatalog
```

When I run it into MS-SQL Management Studio it works and gives result:

> Query Executed Successfully

But when I run it from code-behind it gives error:

> CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user
>   transaction.  
>   CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX statement cannot be used inside a
>   user transaction.

Code-behind is below:

```
var regex = new Regex("^GO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
string[] lines = regex.Split(sql);
SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Length > 0)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = line;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
transaction.Commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly why. In the .NET code, you're wrapping the query in a SQL transaction.

```
SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
...
{
    ...
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
```